# Illeagal character in HTTPPost Method Android

Tags: android, http-post

AM getting continuously the `illegal character` error in this url :

```
http://my.server.com/SelectPerson-0.1/nativeService/businessCardSave?company=Select Person&fullName=Rghh Dgivv&email=uday@uioperr.info&phoneNo=123456789&desiredPosition=Machine Operator&city=Dthhbv&state=AZ&zipcode=5369466&currentEmployer=Fgyevb&currentJobTitle=Dyhg &careerArea=Health and Personal Care&datasource=Android&location=Dthhbv AZ&did=J8C4N275YH1N9LGSZCG
```

Previously there was an extra `&` symbol , so I removed but still am getting same error.

Can anyone help me, in finding this `illegal character` in this `url`.

or anyone specify , the link for `Httpost illegal characters`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to replace the spaces in the url with `%20`

Answer (score 2):

@ should be encoded (see the [full list](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#whatwhy) of characters that need encoding). For simplicity, you should just use `URLEncoder.encode(yourString, "UTF-8");` for each of the values you're putting in the query string of that URL.